# Get all diacritics for a given character in Swift?

Tags: swift, diacritics

How can I get a string or array consisting of all the diacritics for a given character in swift?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: "all the diacritics for a given character" Can you explain what that means? Let's say the character is "y". What would the right answer be here?

Comment: @matt I guess this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic

Comment: @KABoissonneault I know what a diacritic is. What I want to know is what "all the diacritics for a given character" means to the OP.

Comment: @matt Oh, I see what you mean. Like, what languages should we consider? The entire UTF-32?

Comment: for example if i longpress the character i on an iPhone keyboard I get back 6 variations ... it's this list that I'm looking to auto generate (for Latin script)

Comment: I was maybe hoping there was a character set that I could use ..

Comment: You could look up various Latin variations in a Unicode database. There are 17 variations on Latin small letter "i" with diacritic marks as a single character, and of course others can be created by combining characters. I do not know how Apple picks out its "6 variations". There is no magic character set that means "i plus some arbitrary set of diacritic variations on i that Apple thinks are the most common".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unicode standard defines [112 common diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), each of them can combine with every character `a - z` (and their uppercase):

```
let characters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)

for char in characters {
    for i in 0x0300...0x036F {
        let diacritic = UnicodeScalar(i)
        var str = String(char)
        str.append(diacritic)

        print(str, terminator: " ")
    }
    print()
}
```

What you see on the iPhone keyboard is a select number of diacritic marks that Apple has chosen for each character, possibly based on the keyboard's language. You would have to do the same if you don't want to overwhelm your users with choice.

Comment: thanks - I hadn't realized there was such a wide range.